# How to execute ApplicationRunner with Spring Boot (Kotlin)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

This seems silly because it looks like such an easy thing but I am trying to initialize my spring boot project with dummy data using the ApplicationRunner. Can anyone explain why this code is not working? I am expecting it to print to the console the following:

```
Note(id=1, title=Note 1, text=null, user=user)
Note(id=2, title=Note 2, text=null, user=user)
Note(id=3, title=Note 3, text=null, user=user)
```

but instead it doesn't print anything at all.

Here is the implementation:

```
import com.bhanna.bugtracker.notes.Note
import com.bhanna.bugtracker.notes.NotesRepository
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class DataInitializer(val repository: NotesRepository) : ApplicationRunner {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun run(args: ApplicationArguments) {
        println("This should be printing to the console but it is not")

        listOf("Note 1", "Note 2", "Note 3").forEach {
            repository.save(Note(title = it, user = "user"))
        }
        repository.findAll().forEach { println(it) }
    }
}
```

Where Note is:

```
@Entity
data class Note(@Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null,
                var title: String? = null,
                var text: String? = null,
                @JsonIgnore var user: String? = null) {
}

@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(Note::class)
class AddUserToNote {

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    fun handleCreate(note: Note) {
        val username: String =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().name
        println("Creating note: $note with user: $username")
        note.user = username
    }
}
```

and NoteRepository is:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
interface NotesRepository : JpaRepository<Note, Long> {
    fun findAllByUser(name: String): List<Note>
}
```

and finally the main file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class BugTrackerApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<BugTrackerApplication>(*args)
}
```

I thought the @Component annotation meant spring will scan it and execute the underlying run() function since it is implementing ApplicationRunner. Can anyone explain whats going on here?

Comment: any specific error you are facing?

Comment: @SushilBehera no error, just not printing to the console (i updated the question). The function `run()` is not being executed

Comment: How does your main() look like? What is your package structure?

Comment: @FLUXparticle I just added it above. (sorry i tried to keep the code to a minimum but at this point all my cards are on the table lol). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your program and got this error message:

```
Configuration problem: @Configuration class 'BugTrackerApplication' may not be final. Remove the final modifier to continue.
```

So when I changed `BugTrackerApplication` to:

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class BugTrackerApplication
```

it worked as expected.